# Does voting on Japanese Language meta mean agreement/disagreement?

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm an experienced user on Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow meta but haven't participated in other sites too much so far. Therefore I have a question before I start participating more fully on Japanese Language meta.

On SO meta, downvotes and upvotes in addition to their normal usage also mean agreeing / disagreeing with the proposition in the post (see for instance here: [Voting on Meta is not just for (dis)agreement. Update the help center to reflect this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187018/voting-on-meta-is-not-just-for-disagreement-update-the-help-center-to-reflect)):

> Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself behaves, as well as how the software itself works. **On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

Does the same apply to Japanese Language meta?

Comment: Voting up to show this is a good question, not to show my opinion on which way to go (-:

Answer (score 3):

On travel.SE we decided this way, and I believe it's different to what's done on SO:

1. Voting on a question indicates whether you feel it's a question that's worth asking, and whether you feel it was well stated.
2. Voting on questions should never be a vote for or against the proposal in the question since it's too ambiguous with 1. above.
3. Vote on the answers to show which solution to the problem you prefer.

A single answer should not be ambiguously covering more than one outcome if the purpose of the entire thread is to decide a specific issue by community vote. In less important threads this doesn't matter so much.

Comment: Yes, voting on questions would be different. I am personally happy with whichever way as long as it's clear.